# SQL Query, the value didn't carry foward when i change the Year value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I'm trying to carry foward the value from the previous year to the next year. By month with same year is okay, but when I change to new year for example 2017 -> 2018, all the value reset to 0.

```
set @aDept = 'EV'
set @aitemType = '         %'
set @aMonth = 12
set @aYear = 2017

select aa.*, isnull(gb.POPMI,0) POPMI, isnull(hb.PUPM,0) PUPM, (isnull(hb.PUPM,0)) + isnull(gb.POPMI,0) as Opening
from
(select b.t_dicl as Department, c.t_item as Item --all item
  from inforlndb.dbo.twhinr1109980 AS c INNER JOIN inforlndb.dbo.ttcemm1129980 AS b ON  b.t_waid = c.t_cwar and b.t_dicl = @aDept
  group by c.t_item, b.t_dicl) as aa
 full outer join
(select b.t_dicl as Department, c.t_item as Item, sum( c.t_qstk )as POTLI --total production order Issue
  from inforlndb.dbo.twhinr1109980 AS c INNER JOIN inforlndb.dbo.ttcemm1129980 AS b ON  b.t_waid = c.t_cwar
  where c.t_koor = 1 and c.t_kost = 5 and month(c.t_trdt) <= @aMonth and year(c.t_trdt) = @aYear and b.t_dicl = @aDept
  group by c.t_item, b.t_dicl) as fb
  on aa.Item = fb.Item
  full outer join
(select b.t_dicl as Department, c.t_item as Item, sum( c.t_qstk )as POPMI --previous month production order Issue
  from inforlndb.dbo.twhinr1109980 AS c INNER JOIN inforlndb.dbo.ttcemm1129980 AS b ON  b.t_waid = c.t_cwar
  where c.t_koor = 1 and c.t_kost = 5 and month(c.t_trdt) <= @aMonth - 1 and year(c.t_trdt) = @aYear and b.t_dicl = @aDept
  group by c.t_item, b.t_dicl) as gb
  on aa.Item = gb.Item
full outer join
  (select b.t_dicl as Department, c.t_item as Item, sum( c.t_qstk )as PUPM
  from inforlndb.dbo.twhinr1109980 AS c INNER JOIN inforlndb.dbo.ttcemm1129980 AS b ON  b.t_waid = c.t_cwar
  where c.t_koor = 2 and c.t_kost = 3 and month(c.t_trdt) <= @aMonth - 1 and year(c.t_trdt) = @aYear and b.t_dicl = @aDept
  group by c.t_item, b.t_dicl) as hb
  on aa.Item = hb.Item
full outer join
    (select b.t_dicl as Department, c.t_item as Item, sum( c.t_qstk )as PUTL
    from inforlndb.dbo.twhinr1109980 AS c INNER JOIN     inforlndb.dbo.ttcemm1129980 AS b ON  b.t_waid = c.t_cwar
    where c.t_koor = 2 and c.t_kost = 3 and month(c.t_trdt) <= @aMonth and year(c.t_trdt) = @aYear and b.t_dicl = @aDept
    group by c.t_item, b.t_dicl) as ib
    on aa.Item = ib.Item
```

This is the result for aMonth = 12 and aYear = 2017

```
set @aMonth = 12
set @aYear = 2017
Department      Item    POPMI   PUPM    Opening
EV           G00046301  72      25000   25072
EV           G00053001  55      10000   10055
EV           G00251701  220     4500    4720
EV           G00386201  244     16000   16244
EV           G01021001  55      705     760
EV           G01030801  0       2000    2000
EV           G01037101  355     9000    9355
```

Current result for aMonth = 1 and aYear = 2018, the value should be same since there is no data for 1/2018

```
set @aMonth = 1
set @aYear = 2018
Department      Item    POPMI   PUPM    Opening
EV           G00046301  0       0       0
EV           G00053001  0       0       0
EV           G00251701  0       0       0
EV           G00386201  0       0       0
EV           G01021001  0       0       0
EV           G01030801  0       0       0
```

Expected result

```
set @aMonth = 1
set @aYear = 2018
Department      Item    POPMI   PUPM    Opening
EV           G00046301  72      25000   25072
EV           G00053001  55      10000   10055
EV           G00251701  220     4500    4720
EV           G00386201  244     16000   16244
EV           G01021001  55      705     760
EV           G01030801  0       2000    2000
EV           G01037101  355     9000    9355
```

sorry the code is quite messy, im still in learning process =="

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have include expected result.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: Yes. I already include the sample date. @D-Shih

Comment: I'm almost certain this entire query could be simplified to a simple `sum(case...` query with no joins. Also, rather than comparing month and year separately like that, why not just compare a date. It's far simpler to just, say, make a comparison to an `@date` variable that uses something like `datefromparts(@ayear, @amonth, 1)`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Currently, I'm trying to implement your way. I will be very grateful if you can show some sample from my query. @ZLK

Comment: So, first, turn your date into a date, then take your first inner query (`select b.t_dicl as Department, c.t_item as Item --all item
  from inforlndb.dbo.twhinr1109980 AS c INNER JOIN inforlndb.dbo.ttcemm1129980 AS b ON  b.t_waid = c.t_cwar and b.t_dicl = @aDept
  group by c.t_item, b.t_dicl`) and add some sums to the select. e.g. `POPMI = SUM(CASE WHEN c.t_koor = 1 AND c.t_kost = 5 AND c.t_trdt < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @datevariable) THEN c.t_qstk ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: Your methods work. Thank you very much. :D @ZLK